# Completing the diagram using chemfig

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I intend to draw the chemistry of the reaction as depicted below using `chemfig`. Here is what I have done studying examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{*6(-=-=(-CH=[::-90]CH_2)-=)}\rightarrow{->[$h\nu$]}[,1.5]\chemfig{*6(-=-=(-CH= [::-90]CH_2)-=)}
\end{document}
```

This is a sample of the output intended:
[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but could you elaborate more on what your question is, which aspect(s) are you stuck on and what does your current code output?

Comment: Just a note this isn't a `do-this-for-me` website, it is about troubleshooting and solving issues rather then asking to draw stuff for you

Comment: x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/76542990/2777074

Comment: If you post the same question on multiple sites, you should add links to all other versions in every of your questions.

Answer (score 5):

For reactional schemes it is necessary to use `\schemstart \schemestop`

for polymers, see section 12.4 of the ChemFig manual

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
    \chemfig{*6(-=-=(-CH=[::-90]CH_2)-=)}
    \arrow{->[$h\nu$]}[,1.5]
     \chemfig{-[@{upleft,.2}]-CH(-[6,,1]*6(=-=-=-))(-[4])-[0]CH_2-[0]CH(-[6,,1]*6(=-=-=-))-[0]-[@{upright,0.2}]}
     \polymerdelim[delimiters ={[]}, height = 10pt, depth = 100pt, indice = n]{upleft}{upright}
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help @CrocoDuck

Comment: If the answer was helpful and what you wanted, please accept my answer.